# Linux C, How to schedule 10 waiting threads to execute in FIFO?

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, posix, threadpool

I'm using the following conditional thread to lock 10 threads using FIFO scheduling, I need to unlock the threads in the order with which they have arrived to pthread_cond_wait(&cvv, &lock);
I need to know if that is possible or there is no guarantee to have this scenario.

```
struct sched_param param = {.sched_priority = 10};
pthread_cond_t cvv = (pthread_cond_t) PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER;
pthread_mutex_t lock = (pthread_mutex_t) PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;

void *thread(void *v) {
    pthread_setschedparam(pthread_self(), SCHED_FIFO, &param);
    int index = *((int *)v);
    printf("Locking [%d] and waiting\n", index);
    pthread_mutex_lock(&lock);
    pthread_cond_wait(&cvv, &lock);
    printf("Unlockd [%d] => %d\n", index, clock());
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock);
    return NULL;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        t = (pthread_t *) malloc(sizeof (pthread_t));
        int *x = malloc(sizeof (int));
        *x = i;
        pthread_create(t, NULL, thread, x);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        pthread_cond_signal(&cvv);
    }
}
```

The out put is not in ascendant ordered

```
Locking [0] and waiting
Locking [1] and waiting
Locking [2] and waiting
Locking [3] and waiting
Locking [4] and waiting
Locking [5] and waiting
Locking [6] and waiting
Locking [7] and waiting
Locking [8] and waiting
Locking [9] and waiting

Unlocked [0] => 7043
Unlocked [8] => 7084
Unlocked [6] => 7100
Unlocked [2] => 7130
Unlocked [5] => 7294
Unlocked [7] => 7362
Unlocked [3] => 7407
Unlocked [1] => 7463
Unlocked [9] => 7482
Unlocked [4] => 7559
```

Comment: There is no guarantee that your second `for` loop will wake up all of the threads. `pthread_cond_signal(&cvv)` will not do anything at all if there is not already some thread waiting to receive the signal. Nothing but luck prevents your main thread from signalling the condition variable at a moment when no thread is waiting.

Comment: This smells like an XY problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`pthread_setschedparam` is probably not available to you, as it requires privilege.  You do not check the return values of these calls, but you will likely find that they are failing with `EPERM`.  They do so for me.

> I need to unlock the threads in the order with which they have arrived
>   to pthread_cond_wait(&cvv, &lock); I need to know if that is possible
>   or there is no guarantee to have this scenario.

Yes, you can do this, but you will need to roll your own.  Here's one scheme that can accomplish it:

- establish three global counters, say `in`, `out`, and `next`, access to which are protected by the mutex.  Initialize all of them to 0.
- Each thread passes through the lock like so:

  - before waiting on the CV it increments `in` and records the new value.  This is its "ticket".
  - it tests whether its ticket is equal to `next` and `next` is less than or equal to `out`, and waits on the CV only if one or both of these conditions is not met.
  - if it does wait, then when it returns, it loops back to testing its ticket against the current value of `next`.
  - before it proceeds past the lock, it increments `next`.
  - finally, it broadcasts to the CV (this may be either before or after unlocking the mutex)
- to unlock the next thread,

  - increment `out`
  - if `next` is still 0 then increment it, too
  - call `pthread_cond_broadcast` (*not* `pthread_cond_signal`)

Of course, all accesses to `in`, `out`, and `next` must be performed under protection of the mutex, which should be the same one used with the CV.

Note that that scheme permits threads to grant unlocks prospectively, when no threads are presently locked.  That will actually solve one of the problems with your current implementation, but if you prefer, you can rework it using only `in` and `next`, making the thread performing the unlocking wait until `in` exceeds `next`.  This can be achieved with use of the same CV.  Details are left as an exercise.

Answer (score 1):

So far as I'm aware, there's no special way in which threads contending on the same resource can be lined up in order. That applies for semaphores, and I think for condition variables too. The OS will simply schedule whichever thread of the highest priority contends first for the resource.

So you'd have to have 10 separate syncronisation primitives (semaphores, condition variables, whatever), each one for a single thread.

BTW the good ordering of the first part of your output is just good luck; there's absolutely nothing to guarantee that successive calls to pthread_create will actually result in the new thread running there and then in that order.

Answer (score 0):

How about ten mutexes or semaphores. All start out locked. Each thread waits on one lock, and as soon as it's done its work it unlocks the lock for the next thread (n + 1). The last thread will unlock the first lock.

Or, of the threads will only execute once, in order, why use threads at all? If it's a requirement for the exercise, and the end of the last thread is the end of your program, the threads should exit after unlocking the lock for the next thread, and the last thread won't have a lock at all to unlock. Then the main thread (your `main` function) just waits (through `pthread_join`) for all threads to finish.

---

Pseudo-code of the thread function:

```
void *function(void *)
{
    wait(lock[n]);

    // Do work...

    unlock(lock[n + 1]);
}
```